# Where should I store email templates for emails sent out at the end of a batch run?

Tags: c#, email, batch-file, templates

So I'm writing this EXE to process refunds, and when the job's done, we're sending out an email to a list of users that will probably be like:

*DO NOT REPLY*

Refund processing has completed. N refunds were successfully processed. We encountered N errors. Please check http://whatever.url for a detailed report.

Thanks,

A computer

*DO NOT REPLY*

So, we're not talking about grinding out hundreds of emails here, just one a day with the relevant info slipstreamed in. It's unlikely that this email will ever be modified, and never by non-technical staff. How should I go about storing this and processing the template into the email? C# String.Format style with {0} and {1}, etc? XML/XSLT (seems like a hassle)? Do I store the template in App.config or put it in the database or something different altogether?

What did I ever do before StackOverflow? :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would take the easy way out. I assume you want to send a HTML mail message here.

I suggest you create a HTML file with how you want the mail to look. Replace all names/variables with things like #COMPANYNAME#. save the file and rightclick on your Project in Visual Studio. Go to Properties  then Resources. Now drag the HTML file into the resources and give it a decent name (here: MyMailTemplate).

Now from your code you can refer to it from Properties.Resources.MyMailTemplate. You can use it as a string. Replace the #PARAMETER# text with the actual values.

Done and easy to edit!

Comment: taking this one, it seems easiest. Thanks!

Comment: Just came back to heap extra praise on this answer. I'm already done with the entirety of the email portion of my app! Thanks again!

Comment: When is this resource reloaded? After a build?

Comment: @Sinjai the resources are compiled into the code. If you update the resources you'll have to rebuild your project and release a new version. This is based on Chris' requirements that the resources almost never change and are only handled by the dev team. If you want to change the resources without rebuilding I'd recommend to store the templates as text files and load them into strings using `File.ReadAllText`. You can even upscale the solution and store them in a database or host them at a URL.

Comment: Got it. Should work fine for ASP.NET MVC activation emails... The email will be seldom updated and when it is a rebuild is IMO no problem since there's nothing to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

I usually store the template in a text file with custom placeholder markup, although you could use the c# String.Format style for the placeholders. I reference the filename in the app.config, I can then load the text template in, replace the markup and send the email.

This keeps everything pretty simple and it's possible to update the email text without any recompiling.